# Polo gti 2013 smoke when pulling away slow

Tags: engine, oil, vw, smoke

My polo GTI started giving a puff of smoke white/grey maybe when I pull out slowly or roll down hill, but if I drive the car hard it doesn't smoke.
It also uses around 500ml oil in month or two.

I put the car on the diagnostics and it shows nothing wrong
I’m lost now, What do I do?

Comment: Who did the diagnostics?  Did they perform a compression or leakdown test?  If not, have these done before you do anything else.  That said, the first thing to try is to clean up the filters as VWs can breath heavily when they get older and tend of clog their crankcase ventilation filters.

Comment: My mac did the check

Comment: I also try Compression or leak test